# Why is isEulerian() in JGraphT an undefined symbol for me?

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

I'm trying to use JGraphT to check whether or not a graph is Eulerian. I see that function `isEulerian()` is given. I'm using `UndirectedGraph` from one of JGraphTs demos so I'm sure this part of the code is correct. What's more, I've checked that this function returns boolean. Still, I receive an error. What is wrong?

Also I see that `isEulerian()` is static so I don't need an object of this class to use the function.

Useful link: http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/EulerianCircuit.html

```
package org.jgrapht.alg; 
import java.util.List;
import org.jgrapht.alg.*;
import org.jgrapht.*;
import org.jgrapht.graph.*;

public class testowa{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> stringGraph = createStringGraph();
        // note undirected edges are printed as: {<v1>,<v2>}
        System.out.println(stringGraph.toString());
        boolean check = isEulerian(stringGraph);
    }



    private static UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> createStringGraph()
    {
        UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g =
            new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

        String v1 = "v1";
        String v2 = "v2";
        String v3 = "v3";
        String v4 = "v4";

        // add the vertices
        g.addVertex(v1);
        g.addVertex(v2);
        g.addVertex(v3);
        g.addVertex(v4);

        // add edges to create a circuit
        g.addEdge(v1, v2);
        g.addEdge(v2, v3);
        g.addEdge(v3, v4);
        g.addEdge(v4, v1);

        return g;
    }
}
```

The error I keep receiving :

```
testowa.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        boolean check = isEulerian(stringGraph);
                        ^
  symbol:   method isEulerian(UndirectedGraph<String,DefaultEdge>)
  location: class testowa
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined any method named `isEulerian();`

According to docs [docs](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/EulerianCircuit.html#isEulerian-org.jgrapht.UndirectedGraph-)

You have to pass some parameter.

`public static <V,E> boolean isEulerian(UndirectedGraph<V,E> g)`
This method will check whether the graph passed in is Eulerian or not.

Also, you need to **import** class `EulerianCircuit`. Then you can use `EulerianCircuit.isEulerian(stringGraph)`

Comment: I am aware thet isEulerian will check whether the graph is Eulerian or not. I'm not sure why should I delare it? I want to use this function from the JGraphT library which I have added.

Comment: You have edited your question after my answer. What is the problem coming now ? Can you please elaborate

Comment: Call the method like this EulerianCircuit.isEulerian(stringGraph)

Comment: The same. I've written boolean check = isEulerian(stringGraph);  I've updated the error and I don't know how to correct the error.

Comment: Check the edited answer. You have to import the class EulerianCircuit